# Expanding variable in command FROM in a Dockerfile with spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, docker, dockerfile, environment-variables

Due to a particular management of images in my company, I cannot use the same base image for the several stages of the CI pipeline of my application. For that purpose I need to specify to my Dockerfile which image is going to be retrieved depending of the environment.

I have a typical Dockerfile but instead of expanding variables in VAR or similar, which would be done once the image is already loaded and thus it would be an environment variable, I need to expand the variable with the help of Spring Boot.

My Dockefile starts with

FROM ${image.env}

image.env will be defined in my application.yaml. More likely I'll implement profiles in my maven pom so image.env in application.yml gets rewritten with the appropriated value depending on the environment passed to the mvn install -p command

Is this a good way to choose an image depending on the environment? Should I try a different approach?

Comment: A typical setup is to use an identical image in every environment.  Building a different image from a different base in each environment seems like a huge integration-testing challenge.  In theory you can [use Dockerfile `ARG` before `FROM`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-arg-and-from-interact) to support this case, but what you're describing doesn't seem like a best practice.

Comment: Absolutely. I'm totally aware but this is a company constrain I have to deal with. You don't develop SW over a DEV branch, you develop your DEV version of your SW on a final release branch. This is unfortunately where I am